# How to distinguish between GRPS and 3G in IOS?

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

Using Reachability, I know if the current network is connected via WIFI or WWAN. The WWAN includes GPRS and 3G. If the current network is WWAN, I want to know if it is GPRS or 3G. Does Reachability have some way of to distinguishing between GRPS and 3G in ios?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can (at least, not without using private API). And why would you? If you need good connection quality, better measure actual quality than rely on assumptions based on the mobile tech used.

A 3G connection with poor signal strength is not guaranteed to be faster than a good GPRS connection.

Comment: Thanks your answer. You are right. No matter 3G or GPRS,if it's good connection quality,then we can do what we want to do. If only from aspects of technical,could we distinguish between GRPS and 3G in ios?

Comment: As I said, I don't think it's possible with the official frameworks.